Field startHistoryId getting invalid forcing us to rescan the entire mailbox to get a new startHistoryId
We are using Datto SaaS to backup mailbox for a tenant in google workspace.
Our support on that platform has reasons to believe there is an issue on googles side causing their api calls to do backups to scan entire mailboxes
Field startHistoryId getting invalid forcing us to rescan the entire mailbox to get a new startHistoryId.
Method: users.history.list | Gmail | Google for Developers
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/lis
It appears that Google may have expired the bookmark, which forces the system to re-scan the entire mailbox. This is uncommon but can occasionally happen. Microsoft services have similar technology with the same, but it should be rare on both sides.
If this issue becomes frequent, we recommend reaching out to Google support to investigate why the bookmarks are expiring so often for multiple mailboxes
Some errors:
Error Message:
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Invalid email or User ID" }
Error Message:
org.apache.pekko.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[pekko://lego/user/$A#-884571167]] after [30000 ms]. Message of type [datto.rabbit.PublishActor$Publish]. A typical reason for AskTimeoutException is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
Error Message:
datto.http.google.mail.ApiErrors$TooManyRequestsError: User-rate limit exceeded. Retry after 2024-10-04T09:20:55.431Z
These arre Datto Backups making API calls. Datto has suggested we seek help from google.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As per Method: users.history.list:

A historyId is typically valid for at least a week, but in some rare circumstances may be valid for only a few hours.

This indicates that the startHistoryId getting invalid and forcing us to rescan the entire mailbox to get a new startHistoryId. is an expected behavior.
However, if you're experiencing anything unusual that needs to be reached out to Google support, that should be possible by going to Google Workspace developer support.
You may also find additional information on where to look for general Questions & advice and Developer product feedback on Find support for the Gmail API.
